# Set input-timezone in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an input on my website and my timezone is utc+2h:

```
var startDate = "01/01/2019"
result = moment(startDate).utc().format();
alert(result);
```

This gives back 2018-12-31T23:00:00+00:00, but what I need for the api is 
2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 (first of month at utc timezone), so what i need is more or less set the input timezone to already be utc.
Is there a way to do this with Moment.js? (else I could do the whole thing manually of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to give me the right result:

```
var startDate = "01/01/2019"
result = moment.utc(startDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").format();
alert(result);
//2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: The second argument of the UTC function seems a bit off

Answer (score 3):

You can  use [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

You can set default time zone to UTC [ref](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/)

> By default, moment objects are created in the local time zone.
> Local time zone - it's a time zone which is set in a browser or on your node.js server.

To change the default time zone, use moment.tz.setDefault with a valid time zone.

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");
```

OR

You can explicitly set timezone, when parsing date:

```
m = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "Europe/Berlin");
```

And convert it to timezone you require later, like:

```
m.tz("UTC");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This would still mean that the input is set to a timezone and not UTC, so if I set it to London it would be UTC in winter but still +1h in summer.

Comment: If you're talking about daylight saving time, You can use [`isDST()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/) to check if time is DSTShifted. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: would also be possible to do that and then manually adapt it. but I found another way to directly do it (see other answer)